# Save cookies from specified site to file on my server

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

For my example , i'll use this variables :

- first_site.com = my website where i will execute the cookie get commands
- specified_site.com = my second website that the client is already logged in
- my_server.com = my server adress where i have a php script to handle the received data

the user is already connected to first_site.com and specified_site.com

and i want to get cookies from "first_site.com" and save them to "my_server.com"

Any way to do that , with php or javascript ?!

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If both sites are yours and you have access to the server-side code on both sites, then you can have the first server forward the cookies to the second server using server-to-server communication.

The "same origin" protections built into a browser try to prevent you from doing what you want to do from purely client code (without involving both servers).

This is because you can only retrieve cookies when your page is on the domain that the cookie belongs to.  And, you can only send the cookie (using ajax) to a server on the same domain as the page.  So, you can't send one domain's cookie to another server.  This is an obvious security violation which the browser intends to block with its "same origin" protections.  You can read about those protections [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript&ei=p3pLUYWIG4bKiwKOoYD4CQ&usg=AFQjCNEWPbryDUJDEOIJJ3661cxWzgMgiQ&sig2=MB4SHI-rOG5H4DPT93Qszw&bvm=bv.44158598,d.cGE).

If, you have a cooperating server from the first site, you can have that server retrieve the cookie when it is sent along with the original page request and then that server could send the cookie along to your second site using server-to-server communications.  If the first domain is not yours where you can modify the server-side code, then obviously you can't run code on that server to do this.

Comment: both sites are mine ;)  but i'm new to this so i need help  , 
i own first_site.com and specified_site.com

Comment: On the first site, you will need to access the cookies that are sent with the page request in your PHP.  I don't know PHP myself, but [this  page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) looks like it explains how you read cookies from the current request.  You will then need to send them to the second site.  There are many ways to do that server-to-server communication.  You will need to pick a method, code the sending side and then add code to the second server to respond to that communication.

Comment: Here's a simple example of sending data from one server to another using the PHP library cURL: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that, as it would be a hudge security flaw.

Imagine if I made a website saving all your PHPSESSIDs, I could access your profile on many websites...

Comment: thansks for your answer, but i think you didn't understand what i want to do , 
i want to log users info (connected to my first site ) from my second one , and save the data to my server

Answer (score 0):

These are few of the options. Not the best ones though. Some general pointers to get you started:

a. You can also consider setting up VPN. This whitelist the IPS from both the servers.

1. You can create a REST API containing your cookie info(not public though)!!
2. Make your cookie data available on App1;
3. Make your cookie available as a Cookie object that can be served through a Request/Response Object
4. using "same origin" policy; you can have app2 talk to app1

Comment: yep thats it ;) , how to talk from app2 to app1 (i mean sendin cookies from app2 to app1